# NER English model

Tags: model, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I see the NLP online demo at http://corenlp.run/ uses different NER classes than the downloaded version. The online demo for example uses NER tags Country, Title, Present_Ref, Date, City, State_or_Province, etc. But these tags are not there in 3-class, 4-class or 7-class models. Is the online demo using some different model? If yes, where can we download that model from?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the `regexner` annotator which runs some rules to get more specific NER tags such as STATE_OR_PROVINCE.

Comment: Thanks for responding. That resolved part of my confusion. And the remaining confusion is, Can we have access to the regexner file that the online demo at http://corenlp.run/ uses?

Comment: edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_caseless.tab, 
edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/regexner_cased.tab ... these files are in stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models.jar